# How navigate from default browser back to the application? Detox

Tags: ios, emulation, detox

I'm trying to check if icon with url redirect to default browser and then I need to go back to the my Application. On the iOS emulator there is button back to application but I cannot tap on it. Any suggestion?

Here is my test:

```
it.skip('12. Check icon with site and go back to App', async () => {
    await element(by.id('icon.Site')).tap();
    // you are transfer to Safari
    await element(by.traits(['button']).and(by.label('Application'))).tap();
  });
```